# what is ${#authorization} in thymeleaf when using spring security

Tags: spring-security, thymeleaf

`${#authentication}` is `Authentication.java`, and you can see that from source code if you print it. However tring to print `${#authorization}` throws an `java.lang.Stackoverflow` error. And `Authorization.java` does not have an `expression()` method, even though `${#authorization.expression('hasRole(''ROLE_ADMIN'')')}` works. So what is `${#authorization}`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm using `thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4` integrated with `Spring Security 4`. `${#authorization}` is an instance of `org.thymeleaf.extras.springsecurity4.auth.Authorization`.

For example:

```
<div th:text="${#authorization}"></div>
```

Prints:

```
org.thymeleaf.extras.springsecurity4.auth.Authorization@61ee2eca
```

The class has an `expression` method, please see [here](https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity/blob/3.0-master/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4/src/main/java/org/thymeleaf/extras/springsecurity4/auth/Authorization.java#L99-L106).

But the method is also available in `thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity3`. See [here](https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity/blob/3.0-master/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity3/src/main/java/org/thymeleaf/extras/springsecurity3/auth/Authorization.java). The utility objects (authentication and authorization) are documented [here](https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity).

Hope that helps!